# Receiving Non English Facebook Native Ads With MoPub

Tags: facebook, mopub, facebook-monetization-manager

**Is there a way to control the location of ads requested via the Facebook Monetization center as does not seem to be a such options via MoPub?**

## Expected

English speaking native ads showing with MoPub's Facebook Native Ads integration passing the correct `Location` data.

## Observed

Non English ads showing despite a San Francisco Lat/Long `Location` object being passed to MoPub.

## Configuration

I am receiving native ads that are not in English and appear to be targeted for a different region. I've implemented the `moPubAdapter.loadAds(...)` method as described in the MoPub documentation for the the [RequestParameters](https://developers.mopub.com/docs/android/data-passing/#native-ads).

According to a sample request from the MoPub logs in Android Studio the correct lat/lng is being used: 37.78378378378378-122.44880571614736 which are the coordinates for San Francisco where I currently am. Also, it is not just one or two ads or a specific region. Ads are showing in Spanish, French, Thai, etc.

[French Ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqz1E.png)
[Spanish Ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMM6n.png)

Answer (score 0):

Due to MoPub's response below it seems that there must be a way to target monetization placements via Facebook's dashboard...

**MoPub's response**

> When reviewing your account, we observed that you don't have Marketplace enabled and all your impressions seem to served through networks. Note we can't influence nor control any creative served through networks, since these creatives are served by the network SDKs.
>
> On a different note, there is no way to guarantee that an english speaking user will only see english ads. If an advertiser purchases that impression opportunity, they have the option of sending the non-english creative.
>
> When it comes to Marketplace, one possibility to influence the language of your ads, is by passing the language information to DSPs through Keywords. You can find more information here: https://developers.mopub.com/docs/marketplace/openrtb/#3211-object-device
>
> It is also worth to highlight that the main language in which the device is set up is will be the prevalent one when it comes to the language for the ads, but in this case, since it was your own device, we assume it is English.

**Facebook Documentation**

[Set CPM Targets](https://www.facebook.com/help/publisher/133212460594681?helpref=faq_content) describes how to set CPM targets based on location which could help filter, but isn't directly enabling or disabling specific geos.

Also, it is unclear if setting CPMs in Facebook is necessary if they are already defined for an Ad Unit in MoPub.

*ie: Facebook CPM set to $3 and MoPub CPM set to $5. Will this have a waterfall effect, first filtering out all CPMs on Facebook that are less than $3, then MoPub will filter out everything less than $5?*